# Querying objects in a list by class type vs string identifier - Best practices

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, solid, typescript

I have a class `Character` who has a list of `Spell` objects that he can cast.

```js
abstract class Spell {
    name: string
    manaCost: number

    abstract cast() { ... }
}

class InvisibilitySpell extends Spell { ... }
class FireballSpell extends Spell { ... }

class Character {
    mana: number
    spells: Spell[]

    addSpell(spell: Spell) {
        this.spells.push(spell)
    }
}
```

Casting spells requires accessing the correct spell by index in the `.spells[]` array

```js
let char = new Character()
char.addSpell(new InvisibilitySpell())
char.addSpell(new FireballSpell())
char.spells[0].cast() // casts Invisibility spell
char.spells[1].cast() // casts Fireball spell
```

To improve the ergonomics of the interface and implement mana requirements, I plan on adding a `castSpell` method to the `Character` class that will delegate to the correct spell object, but I am not sure what the best practice is for handling the query.

I could query by the string value of the `.name`

```js
class Character {
    ...
    castSpell(spellName: string) {
        let spell = this.spells.find(spell => spell.name === spellName)
        if (spell && spell.manaCost <= this.mana) {
            spell.cast()
        }
    }
}
```

```js
char.castSpell('Invisibility')
```

Or I could query by the type itself

```js
class Character {
    ...
    castSpell(spellType: typeof Spell) {
        let spell = this.spells.find(spell => spell instanceof spellType)
        if (spell && spell.manaCost <= this.mana) {
            spell.cast()
        }
    }
}
```

```js
import { InvisibilitySpell } from './spells/InvisibilitySpell'

char.castSpell(InvisibilitySpell)
```

What software design considerations or technical implications might there be for doing one over the other, and are there approaches even better than these two?

Comment: This is a very painful, and unidiomatic approach. Instance of tests are not reliable but using strings to differentiate makes the use of classes relatively redundant. How about some plain old objects with a `kind: "fire" | "invisibility" | "whatever";` tag property that will let the language understand exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Querying by type is bad(tm) because you are fighting against OOP, the idea of which is that you can call spell.Cast() and not have to know the type.

More concretely you might have to subclass say `Fireball` into `FireballAtSea` and `FireballOnLand` or something but not want to have that mapping hardcoded into your character class.

You could also change the array to a Map or hashmap type object for faster lookup.

Comment: `spells: { [k: string]: Spell }` has a much nicer type than `spells: Spell[]` if you want to lookup by name.